# Solution of Differential Equations, Imaginary roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Below is the image of the solution of the differential equation. The differential equation gives imaginary roots when finding the characteristics equation. In the step below the step pointed out with the arrow, where does the root of D go with the negative sign in the expression?

[This image is the screenshot of the solution manual of the book Mathematical methods by SM Yusof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAqsr.png)

Comment: It should be $\pm$. Of course, when a polynomial has real coefficients, we know a complex root always has its conjugate as a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That root is ultimately immaterial since we have a solution of the form

$$e^{\alpha x} \Big( c_1 \cos(\beta x) + c_2 \sin(\beta x) \Big) $$

where $\beta = \sqrt{11}/15$ and $\alpha = -1/3$, and $c_1,c_2$ are hitherto undetermined constants.

If we replace $\beta$ with $-\beta$ then we have

$$e^{\alpha x} \Big( c_1 \cos(-\beta x) + c_2 \sin(-\beta x) \Big) $$

However, $\cos(x)$ is even and $\sin(x)$ is odd, so this is the same as

$$e^{\alpha x} \Big( c_1 \cos( \beta x) + (-c_2) \sin( \beta x) \Big) $$

The only difference is now that we have $-c_2$ instead. But since $c_2$ is just a constant it ultimately doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me in clearing my confusion.